# skype as a peer to peer

Tags: p2p, skype

I had read many articles regarding skype.

According to them, Skype is a "pure peer to peer network". I have a question regarding this, that question must be asked on skype forum but they do not give early replies.

I noticed that if I login on skype software through PC1 and do some chatting, my chatting is saved on this PC.

If I move to PC2 and login there then I only see my contacts but no chat history. This implies that the contacts are saved on some server because they are accessible on PC2 also.

*Does this mean that skype is not peer to peer?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Skype is not "pure peer to peer" in that respect.

The contact list, as well as the authentication, as you noticed, go through Skype's servers, as well as the calls to landlines. However, computer-to-computer conversations go through a pure peer-to-peer processus, just as FaceTime.

Edit: In 2006, a security conference had [this talk](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-europe-06/bh-eu-06-biondi/bh-eu-06-biondi-up.pdf) that gives a lot of information about how Skype really works.

If you look at it from a business perspective, Skype needs to know some information about you:

- who you want to call (your contacts)
- who you are (your profile and password)
- what you spent (but it ties in to "profile")

That's what Skype stores. The rest is stored on your computer (call history, chat history...)

Comment: Thanks Kheldar.My question was genuine or not? please be honest I dont  know who had vote down for it

Comment: Your question was a very poor one for StackOverflow because it asks us to speculate on the properties of a closed system.

Comment: @Sharpzain120 Your question was badly worded, and I think probably will end up being closed, because it's not properly researched in my opinion. I won't ask for close because I feel I might be mistaken, but you should in the future search a bit more before you ask questions, and take the time to make them very clear. You should also look into FOSS P2P technology, since Skype, being secret and proprietary, is not the best system to understand P2P VoIP.

Comment: Skype isn't a bad system to study. Although it is closed, it is very popular and its ability to use massive quantities of bandwidth has prompted numerous academic studies. At one point, it was universities that routed most of Skype's traffic, and they were very interested in what was eating up all their bandwidth! That said, the question was phrased in a way that is likely to provoke discussion rather than a solid answer.

Comment: @ObscureRobot skype is not a closed system.please go through the internet

Comment: Skype is closed in that it is not open source. Yes you can bridge calls to the PSTN network, but you cannot examine Skype's source code. The best you can do is observe the Skype apps from the outside and do your best to inspect the encrypted traffic flowing between Skype nodes.

Comment: @Sharpzain120 I'd advise you, before you tell someone to "please go through the Internet" to check his reputation (ObscureRobot has good rep). Especially if he gave you a solid answer as he did, which shows he does know what he's talking about. If you fail to grasp his point, it's probably not his fault. Then again, we're just trying to help you.

Comment: @Kheldar Your answer was "SKYPE IS NOT PURE PEER TO PEER IN THAT SENSE" means that my question was right and wherever it is written that is pure p2p is wrong.Moreover I surfed the internet but i want to get a sure answer from a skype Officer or anyone who is very close to Skype thats why i posted this question

Comment: It isn't a matter of whether your question was "right" or "wrong", it is a matter of whether your question was a good *fit* for StackOverflow. That there is so much discussion in these two questions argues strongly that this was a rather poor question. StackOverflow is for questions that have definite answers. It seems more like you have a lot of questions about how a VoIP system like Skype works, and your "question" was just the thin end of the wedge.

Answer (score 4):

Skype clearly has both peer-to-peer components as well as client-server components. Trivially, account data is stored in central servers. But audio streams from peer to peer. Call routing metadata might be peer to peer, but there could easily be some server-side components to that as well.

Here is a paper documenting a study of [Skype's architecture](http://saikat.guha.cc/pub/iptps06-skype/).

Here is why it is crazy for Skype to store the actual audio and video streams for calls. A high quality audio codec streams data at 128 kbits / second. That's 16 kBytes per second. Suppose you make 10 minutes of calls a day, every day for a year. That's 365 days times 10 minutes times 60 seconds per minute, for a total of 219,000 seconds per year. 219 kiloseconds times 16 kilobytes per second is 3,504 Megabytes per year, or 3.5 GB per year. Now 3.5 GB of disk space is pretty cheap today, but it isn't free. And it was a lot more expensive five years ago. Why would Skype spend the money on 3.5 GB of storage space per user per year for a free service?

Even worse, if Skype were to run all of the live calls through central servers for any reason at all, they would require enormous (and enormously expensive) bandwidth pipes and routers. The brilliance of Skype's system, from a business perspective, is that the customers provide almost all of the infrastructure required to run the network. The accounting and friends lists is cheap and easy to operate by comparison.

Comment: what about when you make call? the call is saved on server?

Comment: When you say "the call is saved on the server" what do you mean? A record of the call, or the audio of the call? Skype may store records of calls centrally, but there is no way they could afford to store the audio streams from all calls centrally, nor would they want to.

Comment: yes i mean the audio or video call..Are you sure the the call is not stored on server?

Comment: Until Skype makes a public statement that they are or are not storing call data, no one can be sure that they are not. But you can do some quick calculations to see that it is crazy to think that they do.

Comment: If you read my link, you'll find out the call data is actually not going to Skype servers, at least from the best of what reverse-engineering can tell. It's transiting through the networks' nodes.

Comment: If anyone is storing your Skype calls, it is paranoid government agencies.

Comment: @ObscureRobot then why youtube is storing our data?

Comment: @Sharpzain120 There are two classes of "our data" that Youtube stores. First, they store the videos that we upload. They do this because their service is for sharing videos. There is a lot of this data, but Youtube monetizes it with advertising. Hopefully that works out for them. The other class of our data that they store is our browsing information. This information requires vastly less storage than video data. They also use this browsing information for their ads.

Answer (score 2):

It uses a combination of P2P (calls, video, etc) and centralized (login, billing, etc) network.

Take a look [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~salman/publications/skype1_4.pdf) for more information about how Skype protocol works.